# Arteries are not connected in AnatomyPlot3D

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

I started using AnatomyPlot3D for educational use. I noticed that 1) the subclavian artery are not connected to vertebral artery. 2) Common carotid artery is not connected to aortic arch. 3) Brachiocephalic artery looks strange (it looks like superimposition of two arteries. Is there any way to fix them?

```
ImportantArteries = 
{Entity["AnatomicalStructure","Aorta"],
Entity["AnatomicalStructure","BrachiocephalicArtery"],
Entity["AnatomicalStructure","LeftSubclavianArtery"],Entity["AnatomicalStructure","RightSubclavianArtery"],
Entity["AnatomicalStructure","LeftCommonCarotidArtery"],
Entity["AnatomicalStructure","RightCommonCarotidArtery"],
Entity["AnatomicalStructure","RightVertebralArtery"],
Entity["AnatomicalStructure","LeftVertebralArtery"]
};
AnatomyPlot3D[ImportantArteries]
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe report this to WRI?

Comment: Thanks! I asked about this issue to Wolfram Technical Support.